# JL audio amplifler

Tags: power-supply, power

I am wanting to add a 700 watt amplifler on my boat but I am having a very difficult time routing my wire on this house boat. I thought of putting in a 110vac circuit (20 amp) to drive a 12vdc power supply that will supply at 700 watts to a JL audio amplifer. Any recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: I assume you are using a car audio amplifier that requires 4 AWG wire (or heavier) and are wondering about the idea of raising the voltage so you can first use smaller wiring and then convert the voltage back down once it arrives at the amplifier system? If so, how far is the amplifier system (in wiring terms) from your power supply system? How big is the boat, in order words?

Comment: Yes you are correct it is a marine JL audio amplifier. The boat is 52 ft long.

Comment: Okay. Have a look at aviation. This is 400 Hz, 115 VAC. They routinely sell 1000 VA inverters (and much higher rated ones, of course) accepting anywhere from about 20 VDC to 36 VDC at their inputs. They also sell AC to DC converters to get back down to DC (often down to as low as 4 VDC, if you want it.) Aircraft need light weight, reliable systems. Of course, they also need them "TSO'd" so they may cost something. But on a 52' you can probably afford it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide 12V at 700W to an audio amplifier. Instead you provide 12V at a suitable Amperage to the amplifier.
If the amplifier is class-AB and produces an output of 700W then its heating is probably 315W (how will you cool it?) and its current at 12V is (700W + 315W)/12V= 84.6A. You will need a HUGE battery, alternator and wires.
Why deafen your self with such high power?

Comment: Looking at the probability distribution function (pdf) of typical audio (and I'd use the IEC-268 test case, for example), you'll find that for undistorted playing, a class-AB amp should operate with an average output of about 10% of the output maximum power rating. (In other words, buy something rated about 10X what you actually need at the speaker system.) I've no idea if they are using class-AB (you brought that up.) But if so, then perhaps the OP understands this need. (This also implies to deliver about 70 W output, about 200 W will be wasted in the amp -- say 25% efficient.)

Answer (score 0):

As related (simular) to a powerful car stereo, you need;

1) 1 or 2 each 12V 100AH deep cycle batteries. Plus 200 amp fuses for a "just in case" short in the power feeds.

2) A way to charge them if an extended operation at loud volume is planned.

3) 4 gauge or heavier black and red fine stranded wire, plus huge ring terminals and/or set-screw type lugs to distribute power.

4) Super capacitors next to each high-powered amp so the bass kicks extra hard.

5) Multiple high performance speakers to make it LOUD without expecting it all from one set of speakers. Stay with 8" or 10" woofers for tight bass, which means using 10 gauge or 8 gauge Monster cable to hook them to the amplifier. If possible keep the amplifiers close to the speakers.

*This will take time and cost thousands of dollars or euros, so I hope you are serious about it and the money needed to make it right.*